# How do I download a file from a http direct link with Node Red?

Tags: file, download, node-red, synology

The title says it all. I have a URL link to an mp4 file. I would need to download that file with node red and store it on the Synology NAS where Node Red is running on.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61087979/edit) the question to show what have you tried. There are core nodes that will do both those parts. (also please read the  doc about what a good question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, I dont know how to display Node Red Flows as text. So Here it goes the flow sequence:
I am trying to download the daily news from a podcast XML.
- A "HTTP request node" GET's an XML from a URL.
- A XML-node parses the XML to Java, which gives me the URL of the wanted file.
- a "change node" moves that file URL to the payload.
..and from here I am stuck. I have the URL as a payload and dont know how to proceed from there.
To download and save the file with the core nodes would be excellent.

Comment: As I said in the original comment [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61087979/edit) the question to add detail, do not try to use comments to add required technical detail. Look down the list of nodes, there is one that should jump out at you to make a http request...

Answer (score 0):

By using an HTTP request node and file out node you will be able to accomplish exactly what you want.